# Passing selected picklist value to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to pass the Selected pick list  value from the apex:inputfield to controller
Ex: apex:inputfield value="{!case.category}"  how to pass the selected value from category. -

```
<apex:inputField value="{!case.Category__c}"> 
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Test" action="{!find}" immediate="true"> 
    <apex:param name="catval" value="{!case.Category__c}" assignTo="{!categoryfield}"/> 
  </apex:actionsupport> 
</apex:inputfield> 
<apex:inputField value="{!case.Sub_Category__c}"/>
```

Comment: Please add your VF page code?

Comment: <apex:inputField value="{!case.Category__c}">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Test" action="{!find}" immediate="true">
 <apex:param name="catval" value="{!case.Category__c}" assignTo="{!categoryfield}"/>
 </apex:actionsupport>
</apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputField value="{!case.Sub_Category__c}"/>

Comment: This is due to `immediate=true` attribute. When that's set, the action method is fired before the getters and setters. Any specific reason for using `immediate=true`?

Comment: no specific reason for that .actually i am trying to hide the field based on the picklist selection.

Comment: If i am not keeping immediate = true then it is showing error in the debug log like tou must enter a value for other mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use actionfunction incombination with some javascript to send values to controller as shown below: (Below is because you are using `apex:inputfield`. For some of the apex components, you can directly us "`assignTo`" to send values to controller)

**Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="tesssss">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="sendValues" reRender="render">
            <apex:param name="value1" value="" assignTo="{!value1}" />
        </apex:actionFunction> 

        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Reason}" onchange="getValues()" styleClass="value1"  />  
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:outputPanel id="render">{!value1}</apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function getValues() {
        var v1 = $j('.value1').val();
        if(typeof v1 != 'undefined') sendValues(v1);
    }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class tesssss {

    public String value1 {get; set;}

    public tesssss(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


}
```